# Use angularjs to display blog images

Tags: html, angularjs, image

I have a blob with url, generating image in console. How to display it in a web page using angularjs.

Here is what I've got in the console...

[image]

[image]

That preview image should display through  tag.

I tried to produce, but can't able to..

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code? What you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Get image, create object URL from your blob and assign src to image:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("img-id");
var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
myImage.src = objectURL;
```

Comment: What should i place in myBlob.. Here i have an url like...  "blob:https://a.b.x.c/b6901e0b-a7fe-4be6-91d5-454h4h54h".. I need this as image source.

Comment: The full value that you've mention

Answer (score 0):

convert blob to base64 in you controller and save that in scope

$scope base64Image = new Buffer( blob, 'binary' ).toString('base64');

and in your HTML file :

```
<div>
<h1>Angular</h1>
<img ng-src="{{base64Image}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the blob content from the database put into a list and use ng-src to display images